# Interfacing with QEMU edu device via Userspace I/O (UIO) Linux driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, qemu, pci

I'm looking at QEMU's [edu device](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/specs/edu.txt) ([source](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/misc/edu.c)) which provides a basic "educational" PCI device within QEMU, that can be accessed as a PCI device from within a QEMU guest like Linux.

I have been trying to get this to work with the [UIO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/uio-howto.html) driver (Userspace I/O) via the UIO PCI generic driver, as an exercise to better understand PCI devices in both QEMU and Linux.

My overall goal is to implement a Linux driver for an FPGA. The FPGA is connected to an ARM Cortex-A53 CPU as a PCI-E device, providing several distinct blocks of memory that will be treated as registers for device configuration. I'm using an x86_64 QEMU initially to become familiar with PCI drivers and hopefully UIO. Note: [vfio](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vfio.txt) has been suggested to me however I believe this relies on IOMMU support which I'm not sure exists on my target platform.

I'm having some trouble with the memory region mapping. The UIO PCI driver is (I think) meant to create entries in `/sys/class/uio/uio0/map` for each addressable region, however from what I can tell, there are no regions being automatically detected or set up when the UIO driver is bound to the edu device.

I'm starting my freshly compiled QEMU (`./configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu`) with a yocto-generated "fairly standard" Linux 4.9 x86_64 distro:

```
$ ./x86_64-softmmu/qemu-system-x86_64 --device edu -m 512 -nographic -serial mon:stdio -append 'console=ttyS0 root=/dev/hda' -kernel bzImage -hda image-qemu.ext3
```

Then within the guest, the edu PCI device is detected:

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Device 1234:1111 (rev 02)
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
00:04.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Device 1234:11e8 (rev 10)
```

Loading the `uio_pci_generic` module and binding it to the edu device:

```
# modprobe uio_pci_generic
# echo "1234 11e8" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/new_id

# ls -l /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:04.0/driver
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Mar 15 01:50 /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/driver -> ../../../bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic
```

Taking a closer look at the device, noting the memory address `fea00000`:

```
# lspci -v -s 00:04.0
00:04.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Device 1234:11e8 (rev 10)
Subsystem: Red Hat, Inc Device 1100
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 10
Memory at fea00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: [40] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Kernel driver in use: uio_pci_generic
```

I built [lsuio](http://www.osadl.org/projects/downloads/UIO/user/lsuio-0.2.0.tar.gz) from source:

```
# ./lsuio -m -v
uio0: name=uio_pci_generic, version=0.01.0, events=0
Device attributes:
vendor=0x1234
uevent=DRIVER=uio_pci_generic
subsystem_vendor=0x1af4
subsystem_device=0x1100
resource=0x00000000fea00000 0x00000000feafffff 0x0000000000040200
msi_bus=1
modalias=pci:v00001234d000011E8sv00001AF4sd00001100bc00scFFi00
local_cpus=1
local_cpulist=0
irq=10
enable=1
driver_override=(null)
dma_mask_bits=32
device=0x11e8
d3cold_allowed=0
consistent_dma_mask_bits=32
config=4è
class=0x00ff00
broken_parity_status=0

# ls /sys/class/uio/uio0/ -l
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 15 01:53 dev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Mar 15 01:53 device -> ../../../0000:00:04.0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 15 01:53 event
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 15 01:53 name
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Mar 15 01:53 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Mar 15 01:53 subsystem -> ../../../../../class/uio
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 15 01:22 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Mar 15 01:53 version
```

According to this, there should be a mappable region starting at `0xfea00000` I think, but no "map" directory appears and I haven't been able to work out why. Attempting to access `/dev/uio0` (read or mmap) results in Error 22: "Invalid argument". Opening the file and scanning to the end shows that the block device has zero size.

Firstly, do I need to manually create these region mappings, or should the UIO driver be setting these up automatically? Does the edu device need to do something extra to make this happen?

Secondly, are there other QEMU PCI devices that are known to work with UIO? Ideally something with a working Linux driver so I can try to understand both the QEMU device side and the corresponding Linux driver side.

On that last note, is anyone aware of a working Linux driver for the edu device?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the [documentation](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/driver-api/uio-howto.html#writing-userspace-driver-using-uio-pci-generic) is slightly ambiguous, enough to confuse at least myself and one other person:

This [long and windy thread](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kvm/msg73837.html) explains that the `ui_pci_generic` driver doesn't actually map PCI BAR regions to the `maps` directory. Instead, the intention is that the standard PCI sysfs interfaces be used:

Therefore I have been able to access the PCI device's memory via a mmap of `/sys/class/uio/uio0/device/resource0`.

However trying to do a blocking read on `/dev/uio0` still results in an "Invalid Argument" error, so I'm not yet sure how to wait for or handle  interrupts using this sysfs interface.

Answer (score 0):

To add to OP answer, it seems that `/dev/uio0` is used for receiving and counting interrupts on `uio_pci_generic` module.
An [example code of using `uio_pci_generic`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/uio-howto.html#example-code-using-uio-pci-generic) shows this:

```c
uiofd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDONLY);
...
/* Wait for next interrupt. */
err = read(uiofd, &icount, 4);
```

`icount` is the number of interrupts received.

When using [qemu's `edu` device](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/docs/specs/edu.txt), you can use `resource0` to access the mapped IO, and use `/dev/uio0` to wait for an interrupt.

Here is a user-space example (extension of the [example code](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.13/driver-api/uio-howto.html#example-code-using-uio-pci-generic) above) of using `uio_pci_generic` to write and read the "card liveness check" of `edu` device that inverts the input, and to trigger `edu` interrupts by writing to "interrupt raise register":

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>


#define EDU_IO_SIZE 0x100
#define EDU_CARD_VERSION_ADDR  0x0
#define EDU_CARD_LIVENESS_ADDR 0x1
#define EDU_RAISE_INT_ADDR 0x18
#define EDU_CLEAR_INT_ADDR 0x19

int main()
{
    int uiofd;
    int configfd;
    int bar0fd;
    int resetfd;
    int err;
    int i;
    unsigned icount;
    unsigned char command_high;
    volatile uint32_t *bar0;

    uiofd = open("/dev/uio0", O_RDWR);
    if (uiofd < 0) {
        perror("uio open:");
        return errno;
    }

    configfd = open("/sys/class/uio/uio0/device/config", O_RDWR);
    if (configfd < 0) {
        perror("config open:");
        return errno;
    }

    /* Read and cache command value */
    err = pread(configfd, &command_high, 1, 5);
    if (err != 1) {
        perror("command config read:");
        return errno;
    }
    command_high &= ~0x4;

    /* Map edu's MMIO */
    bar0fd = open("/sys/class/uio/uio0/device/resource0", O_RDWR);
    if (bar0fd < 0) {
        perror("bar0fd open:");
        return errno;
    }

    /* mmap the device's BAR */
    bar0 = (volatile uint32_t *)mmap(NULL, EDU_IO_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, bar0fd, 0);
    if (bar0 == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("Error mapping bar0!");
        return errno;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Version = %08X\n", bar0[EDU_CARD_VERSION_ADDR]);

    /* Test the invertor function */
    i = 0x12345678;
    bar0[EDU_CARD_LIVENESS_ADDR] = i;
    fprintf(stdout, "Inversion: %08X --> %08X\n", i, bar0[EDU_CARD_LIVENESS_ADDR]);

    /* Clear previous interrupt */
    bar0[EDU_CLEAR_INT_ADDR] = 0xABCDABCD;

    /* Raise an interrupt */
    bar0[EDU_RAISE_INT_ADDR] = 0xABCDABCD;

    for(i = 0;; ++i) {
        /* Print out a message, for debugging. */
        if (i == 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Started uio test driver.\n");
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Interrupts: %d\n", icount);

        /****************************************/
        /* Here we got an interrupt from the
           device. Do something to it. */
        /****************************************/

        /* Re-enable interrupts. */
        err = pwrite(configfd, &command_high, 1, 5);
        if (err != 1) {
            perror("config write:");
            break;
        }

        /* Clear previous interrupt */
        bar0[EDU_CLEAR_INT_ADDR] = 0xABCDABCD;

        /* Raise an interrupt */
        bar0[EDU_RAISE_INT_ADDR] = 0xABCDABCD;

        /* Wait for next interrupt. */
        err = read(uiofd, &icount, 4);
        if (err != 4) {
            perror("uio read:");
            break;
        }

    }
    return errno;
}
```

The result looks something like this:

```
Version = 010000ED
Inversion: 12345678 --> EDCBA987
Started uio test driver.
Interrupts: 3793548
Interrupts: 3793549
Interrupts: 3793550
Interrupts: 3793551
Interrupts: 3793552
Interrupts: 3793553
Interrupts: 3793554
Interrupts: 3793555
Interrupts: 3793556
...
```